# How can I install PHP extensions in a container based on php:7.2-alpine3.7?

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, laravel-5.3, alpine-linux

I'm using Docker to deploy my application and I want to know how to install PHP extensions in a container based on `php:7.2-alpine3.7` container.

How can I do that?

Comment: Chris thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Great i found it :) and voila the solution.

```
  RUN apk --update add wget \
  curl \
  git \
  grep \
  build-base \
  libmemcached-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  imagemagick-dev \
  pcre-dev \
  libtool \
  make \
  autoconf \
  g++ \
  cyrus-sasl-dev \
  libgsasl-dev
```